# Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName "XXX" is not filtering the Role Assignments of the Resource Level via PowerShell

Tags: roles, azure-powershell, azure-rbac

Currently I am trying to automate the Azure Role Assignments using PowerShell script. When I use "Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName "XXX""- I can get the details for some of the users. However, the same command won't return any data for certain users.
For example, i filter the user XXXX via PowerShell and it wont return any data however, I have cross verified in the portal where user XXXX was assigned to the Resource "KeyVault" with Reader Permission (Direct assignment).

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

My Requirement - if we give any user id as input then it will list out all the direct and In-Direct assignments in the Managementgroup, subscription, ResourceGroup and Resource level also. In my case it is not filtering in Resource level (end level)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results below:***

When I tried to run this `Get-AzRoleAssignment` I got all the Roles assigned in username like below:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName XXXXXX@onmicrosoft com
```

[image]

I added a role assignment to the user in the portal, assigning subscription, ResourceGroup, and Resource level roles as seen below:

[image]

When I tried this powershell command using filter It shows results successfully like below:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName   XXXXX@XXXXgmail.onmicrosoft com | FL DisplayName, RoleDefinitionName, scope
```

***Output***:

[image]

```
DisplayName        : baXXX
RoleDefinitionName : Reader
Scope              : /subscriptions/55d5f6cc-a2a3-49de-XXXXX

DisplayName        : baXXXXX
RoleDefinitionName : Reader
Scope              : /subscriptions/XXXXXXa2a3-49de-9109-7ff984b4faef/resourceGroups/sai-rg

DisplayName        : baXXXX
RoleDefinitionName : Reader
Scope              : /subscriptions/XXXXXa2a3-49de-9109-7ff984b4faef/resourceGroups/sai-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/saibabatest123
```

If the same command not returning  any data for certain users:

- Make sure to check that the sign-in name you are using to filter the role assignments is correct. Also  verify the sign-in name you are using in the command is the same for the reader role, which is assigned.
- Check if the sign-in name of certain user,  If the Assigned role assignment is at the subscription level and you are filtering at the resource group level, in that case, command does not return any data.
- See if the cmdlet returns any data, try eliminating the filter criteria. If it does, then you can refine the filter criteria to get the desired result.

Alternatively, You can use the user's email address instead of the sign-in name to filter the role assignments.